# Vote limit doesn't apply to comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, votes

Earlier today I hit the 40-vote mark after going on a voting spree (I'd already gotten Vox Populi once). But I noticed that I could still vote on comments.

**How to reproduce:**

1. Vote the max 40 times in a day, getting Vox Populi if you haven't (there will be an indicator saying "Daily vote limit reached; vote again in *x* hours.")
2. Try to upvote a comment. You will see that you can successfully boost the comment's score.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a bug. These are different kinds of votes (comment votes vs post votes), each with its own limits. Consulting 
[The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) we find that a user has at most 30 comment votes per day, with the following asterisks

- [The automatic upvotes associated with certain close-votes do not count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378783)
- But the deletion of your comments, apparently, [counts toward the same limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238331).